# How much do the Voyagers' attitudes drift over time? How often are their thrusters used for attitude control?

Tags: history, voyager, attitude-determination-and-control

[@Hobbes' answer to *Voyager 1's tape recorder and other angular momentum management issues*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17471/12102) says:

> There are no reaction wheels on Voyager [...] Voyager is not spin-stabilized. It used thrusters for stabilization, to provide a stationary platform for the cameras.

To [*How would the Voyagers finally die if allowed to transmit to the bitter end?* is](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36016/12102)

> In this scenario, the last straw would be the hydrazine freezing which leads to loss of the thrusters.

And to [*Could the Voyager spacecraft be spin-stabilized to keep their high gain antennas pointing towards the Sun (and therefore Earth)?* is](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36009/12102)

> There is enough hydrazine to last beyond the end of the mission, about 25% of total tank volume is still available. From [Descanso volume 4](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/Descanso4--Voyager_ed.pdf), you can see enough hydrazine for attitude control is available to last until 2040/2048
>
> [...]I have found no references to spin stabilization as an option for Voyager operations: because of the above, the Voyager team never had to consider spin stabilization.

The Voyagers have a rather unique situation; after decades in deep space they are still able to perform accurate acceleration measurements via rate-range data from their coherent transponders, and so there was an effort to pay careful attention to their thrusters so as not to interfere with radial velocity measurements.

- [How are the Voyagers' thrusters configured in a novel way to minimize accelerations along Earth-spacecraft axis?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19331/12102)
- [How are Voyager's 16 thrusters oriented?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32223/12102)
- [How do Voyager 1's Trajectory Control Thrusters differ from its Attitude Control Thrusters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23895/12102)
- [What does it mean when the Voyagers "switch thrusters"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37340/12102)

**Question:** How much do the Voyagers' attitude drift over time? How often are its thrusters used for attitude control? Are the valves actuating and thrusters burning once an hour? Once a day? Once a month? Are they both about the same?